# MVC 5 - Serve a static txt file giving 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.6

I have to expose a txt file in my mvc 5 site's url in this path:`www.mysite.com/home/somefile.txt`

The .Net MVC is throwing 404 error.

I already added the handler on web.config

```
    <add name="MyTxt" 
       path="/home/riot.txt" 
       verb="GET" 
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

What else i have to do for this work?

**[Edit 1]**
i created the route like this

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FileRoute",
            url: "home/txt.txt",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetFile" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And i change the web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

And here is my controller

```
        public FileResult GetFile()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,"riot.txt"));
        string fileName = "riot.txt";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

And it is throwing 404 error on url:`http://localhost:10021/home/riot.txt`

**[EDIT 2]** I put the wrong route pattern, after i put the right one `home/riot.txt` in this case. I worked. Thank you guys.

Comment: have you checked your routing, seems it calling "home" controller, do you have action method for it

Comment: I have a HomeController, but i dont have a action for It. I dont know How.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/807/download-files-aspnet-mvc-3-controller-action

Comment: if you don't want controller just access without home

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need the controller because i have a page as Index action. I think the Dot break the route. Do you have another example?

Comment: for extension check this https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/

Comment: by Id http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/download-file-in-mvc-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a root which catches all `/home` requests - which is common in MVC templates. The simplest way is to change you file path:

```
/files/test.txt
```

But if you want to serve the file with `/home` path, you should change your `HomeController`'s name, **OR** doing hard job:

1. Create an action in home named `GetTxt()` for example
2. Define a route just before your home-route with this pattern:

   /home/txt.txt
3. Enable running all modules for all requests in `web.config` by setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute in `system.webServer/modules` path:

But I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thank you for attetion. I edited the question with your sugestion. it didnt worked.

Comment: thank you. It is just a temporary work around. after i'll remove this .

Answer (score 0):

~/ resolves to the application root.

/ resolves to the site root.

```
 Path="/Home/txt.txt"
```

use this `~/` Recommended in asp.net

```
 Path="~/Home/txt.txt"
```